# window.external.[MyFunction] does not work with Outlook VSTO project

Tags: javascript, c#, outlook

I have a VSTO Outlook project that's open external VisuaForce page from Salesforce environment `using "System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser"`.
VF page use JS method `window.external.BrowserSubmitFile(jsondata, bSingleFiling) whereBrowserSubmitFile()` is C# method in Outlook project to exchange information between Salesforce and Outlook.

But now the project was updated for using WebView2 and when trying to call the C# method from the VF page I get this error: `"TypeError: window.external.BrowserSubmitFile is not a function"`

I found in internet, that it could be because I am opening it in browser window, not inside Office app.
Question: how to open web pages inside Office app using WebView2?